# How to set status on Custom Authorize attribute in ASP.NET Web API/MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api2

Right now when we use authorize attribute with asp.net Web API if token unauthorized then it is sending back to the login screen and returning status 200. Instead of that, we want to have status 401 and our custom view. How we can do it.

I have already tried doing below but does not have any success.

```
public class CustomAPIAuthorizeAttribute : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        actionContext.Response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.